# Is it possible to access Flutter assets directly in FFI C function?

Tags: flutter, ffi, dart-ffi

Say I have an asset in Flutter `data.bin`
and another c function

```
void processData(void* data, int size)
```

Is it possible to access this binary asset "data.bin" in C directly?

I understand that I could use `rootBundle.load("data.bin")` and copy the data to C heap buffer. But as the data is very large, I hope it could be done without copy.

Comment: Honestly, if some data is too big to pass to C over FFI, you shouldn't be keeping it in assets. You could try a platform specific approach, like using the Android NDK to open the assets. https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset